# adding uniqueness to dropdown box options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a drop down box with a list of states for all US banks.  The drop down box is listing 6300 states, which is the total number of banks. What I'd like is for the drop down to only list the 50 US states and not every state for each bank.  Is there a uniqueness constraint I can add to this, to just get 50 states and not every state for every bank?  I tried Boli.uniq(:state) and Boli.uniq!(:state) and neither worked.  Here is my view code.  Thank you Ruby community.

```
 <%= collection_select :boli, :boli_id, Boli.order(:state), :id, :state %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you want to submit to server here. But if you want a dropdown with all distinct states, just use:

```
<%= select_tag :name, options_for_select(Boli.uniq.pluck(:state)) %>
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you Hoang!  Would I be able to add the .order method to the code you provided to sort the banks alphabetically?To answer your other question, what I'd like to do, is create a dynamic dropbox arrangement, so user will have a list of banks to select from in the state they selected.  Then once they select a bank, certain information will be displayed.

Comment: Yes you can, just add: `Boli.order(:state).uniq.pluck(:state)` (ascending) or `Boli.order(state: :desc).uniq.pluck(:state)` (descending)